# Did the Sins of the Flesh update break the rolling-with-gauntlets strategy?

Tags: cult-of-the-lamb

Many online sources talk about a possibly unintended feature of gauntlets. They have a combo, where the third strike is the most powerful strike of the combo, but if you roll immediately after making the third strike and attack again, it will continue doing the third-strike animation with the increased damage.

Upon trying this myself in the new update, it doesn't seem to be working. Is this confirmable?